# Running a different api in a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, for-loop

My goal is to log all these APIs for a variety of artists that I have in a list. The thing with the API is that each artist has their own so it has to be called multiple times, once for each artist.

```
var artistList = [...]; //let's say there is a hypothetical 100 artists
var n = artistList.length; //this would be 100

for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urlApi = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=' + artistList[i] + '&api_key=somApiKeyThatWorks&format=json';
    console.log(urlApi);
    request.open('GET', urling, true);

    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(data);
      } else {

      }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
    };

    request.send();
};
```

Right now when I run this and check the console, only the last listed item is shown for data. So I get all these API logged and correctly with the corresponding artist in each API but I only get one JSON logged.

If anyone could tell me how to get it so that each JSON will be logged for each API that would be great. I have a feeling that this is happening because it takes a while for `request.responseText` so it skips it before it's finished, resulting in it only logging the last item in the list. Don't know how to approach this. I also can't use jQuery since I was explicitly asked not to for this assignment.

Comment: What is `urling` in your code? Did you mean `urlApi`?

Comment: It's one API, not one per artist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple: `request` is non-blocking, so it lets the for loop finish when `request.send()` is called. But when the for loop starts the next iteration, `request` is overwritten, so only the *last* request gets logged.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Change `true` to `false` in `request`. This changes it from non-blocking to blocking and will pause the loop until the request finishes and gets a response. Then you're guaranteed it will work.
- Use `map` to collect your results. i.e. call `artistList.map(makeRequest)`, where `makeRequest` returns the result of the XMLHTTPRequest using an artist from `artistList` as an input.

  (I don't guarantee this will work! Look around for something equivalent to an asynchronous request operating over arrays if it doesn't, or use the first method.)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare one object before for loop. and append all records in it.

Example:

```
        var artistList = [...]; //let's say there is a hypothetical 100 artists
        var n = artistList.length; //this would be 100
```

> var results = {};

```
        for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var urlApi = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=' + artistList[i] + '&api_key=somApiKeyThatWorks&format=json';
            console.log(urlApi);
            request.open('GET', urling, true);

            request.onload = function() {
              if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                console.log(data);
```

> results[artistList[i]] = data;

```
              } else {

              }
            };

        request.onerror = function() {
        };

        request.send();
    };
```

Now, you have all data in `results` object.

Hopefully, it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [**Infamous Loop Problem**](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) (scroll to the content where the `The Infamous Loop Problem is discussed`) This is a must know when you are dealing with loops with functions. To get it working use this syntax.

```
request.onload = function(thisRequest) { // this is the current request and now inside this block it will refer to the same request object.
  return function(){
    if (thisRequest.status >= 200 && thisRequest.status < 400) {
     var data = JSON.parse(thisRequest.responseText);
     console.log(data);
    }
    else {
    }
  }

}(request);  //pass the current request as the parameter to this function and execute
```

Explaining the problem here,

The request variable changes for each loop, And since the `onload` function is not executed but only applied, the request variable keeps changing till the end of the loop. So when the for loop exits the last value of `request` is applied to all the functions.

To overcome this problem we must execute the function in each loop by passing the current request object of the loop as a parameter, Now inside this function scope the request variable will always be the one which was passed as parameter.